# Changing button font text color, within nav bar

Tags: html, css

I have a button embedded in my nav bar and Im wondering how to change the font color of the button without changing the rest of the nav bar text color.

Button is on a green background with grey text.  Need to make white text on green while keeping other tab text grey.

```css
.button2 {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background: #82b440;
  border-radius: 1em;
  border: solid;
  border-color: #82b440;
  color: #82b440;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 4em;
  padding: 0em 1.3em;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  text-decoration-color: white;
  -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="container">

    <!-- Logo -->
    <a href="index">
      <img src="images/Picture2.png">
    </a>

    <!-- Nav -->
    <nav id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="page">Other Page Text</a>
        </li>
        **
        <li><a href="quote" class="button2">Button Text</a>
        </li>**

      </ul>
    </nav>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand? Can't you just target the .button2 class as you have done? This will ensure only that button(or other buttons with the same class) is effected.

Comment: `color: #82b440;` Change that.

Comment: I've tried that and it seems that the nav. ul. li font color overrules a color change in the button specifically. The color: #82b440 (green) is effectively useless as the text within is currently grey as thats what the nav. ul. li. defines it to be.

Answer (score 2):

Change the `color` attribute of `.button2` to `#FFFFFF` or `white`. Otherwise, you are telling it to have green text, which is the same colour as the background.

Comment: I've tried that and it seems that the nav. ul. li font color overrules a color change in the button specifically.  The color: #82b440 (green) is effectively useless as the text within is currently grey as thats what the nav. ul. li. defines it to be.

Comment: Try using !important on the `color` rule to make it override, that could help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay,

You should know that the attribute responsible for font coloration there is `color:` so changing if to something else would change the font color without destroying anything else

Eg.

```
color: #F5F5F5;
```

```css
.button2 {
-moz-appearance: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-o-appearance: none;
-ms-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
background: #82b440;
border-radius: 2px;
border: 1px solid #82b440;
color: #f5f5f5;      /* What matters here */
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
letter-spacing: 1px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 1.4em;
text-decoration-color: white;
-moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
 }

.button2:hover{
border: 1px solid #8fc04e;
   background: #8fc04e;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
}
```

```html
<a href="#quote" class="button2">Button Text</a>
```

Comment: Hi there, for some reason it appears that that font color.  This is what is defining the nav bar font color                      #nav > ul > li a {
     color: inherit;
     line-height: 4em;
     letter-spacing: 2px;
     text-decoration: none;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-weight: 400;
     font-size: .8em;
                }

Comment: I believe the inherit property takes up from what is in it parent element, so in actual sense changing to that won't really do much